# Does Sphinx natively support documentation on side-effects?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, side-effects

Other documentation tools support specific tags in order to document side-effects (such as the `@modifies` tag in JSDoc, for example). I was wondering if Sphinx or any plugin may offer something similar, as I could not find anything so far.

Comment: What does `@modifies` do? It's not mentioned here: https://jsdoc.app/.

Comment: @mzjn true, and I've in fact read complaints in their GitHub's threads for the tag not being documented in jsdoc.app, but it appears [in the Closure documentation](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#nosideeffects-modifies-thisarguments).

Comment: @mzjn just found again [this one discussion](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1283) on the topic as a JSDocs's GitHub issue. Pretty hidden...